# How can I identify functions and their size in a x86-64 executable binary (PE)

Tags: assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering, disassembly, decompiler

Using an x86 disassembler such as capstone, are there known algorithms that I can use to identify functions and their respective sizes in a portable executable?

I found [Architecture Agnostic Function Detection in Binaries](https://binary.ninja/2017/11/06/architecture-agnostic-function-detection-in-binaries.html) which is exactly what I am trying to achieve, but this software is closed source and the explanation is not technically detailed enough for me to implement an actual algorithm.

The article mentions the use of a linear sweep, but it doesn't specify a sweep for what?

Furthermore, are functions always contiguously stored, meaning that they do not intertwine?
Otherwise what I am trying to achieve may not be possible in the first place.

I tried scanning for function's epilogues and prologues without success.

Comment: Do you care about the common case or about detecting 100% of all "functions"? In one extreme example, if I created a PE file from pure assembler I could have any kind of function that intermix or use silly calling conventions or have pure spaghetti code that simply jumps around itself without any structure. If the executable was built from some other language then odds are there's more structure there.

Comment: In compiler output, yes they're contiguous except for alignment padding.  (Some binaries have their compiler output post-processed by an obfuscator).  Re: scanning for epilogues and prologues: tail-duplication optimization means they can have multiple paths of execution that lead to a `ret` or tailcall `jmp` for the same function.  In compiler-generated code you'll normally only find `push` instructions early in a function (or before a `call` to functions with many args, in non-Windows), but not necessarily as the first instruction.

Comment: @PeterCordes With profile-guided optimization, even compiler output can break functions into non-contiguous chunks.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Oh right, yeah, splitting cold code paths out into a `.text.cold` section for better iTLB and icache locality of the hot parts.  Good point.

Comment: @JoachimSauer My goal is to identify as many functions as possible, but 100% is not a requirement. I can also ignore edge cases where function's basic blocks are not contiguous as well.